# Jenkins build failing for a test case when it have SendKeys() function

Tags: selenium2, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

if I run my test suite (Selenium WebDriver) with test cases giving text output only using

```
System.out.println("some text");
```

Build status is successful using Jenkins

But

whenever it comes to the step where (sendKeys) involved build gets failed status with following message

Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure Finished: FAILURE

e.g step

```
driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("test");
```

Do i need to use headless browser or any plug-in to achieve success

Following is the content of run.bat file

```
java -cp bin;lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: May be your batch file has some issue?

Comment: Does the test runs fine when used without jenkins?

Comment: yes it does well if I execute the command written in bat file via command prompt after setting classpath

let me include the command written in run.bat file on main thread

Answer (score 1):

Your error indicates that your batch file is throwing an unhandled exception.  Likely this is something like "element not found". Your log files will tell you more.